# Unable to build example for CUDA NVlabs SASSI tool

Tags: makefile, cuda, nvidia-sass

I am attempting to build and run the example code from the NVlabs project [SASSI](https://github.com/NVlabs/SASSI) which can be used to instrument CUDA code. However, I am struggling to get even the included sample `Makefile` and `matrixMul.cu` to build and run properly.

I have tried adding the `--maxrregcount=16` and [`-rcd=true`](https://github.com/NVlabs/SASSI/blob/master/doc/sassi-user-guide.pdf) nvcc flags, but I think my real issue is with linking properly to the SASSI libraries. All of the library paths listed in the nvcc output below resolve to actual directories with `.so` files.

Any tips or debugging steps are much appreciated.

---

```
$ make clean
```

> rm -f -f matrixMul *.o

```
$ make branch
```

> /usr/local/sassi7//bin/nvcc -I./inc  -c -gencode
>   arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50
>   -Xlinker "--wrap=main" -Xlinker "--wrap=exit" -lineinfo -Xptxas --sassi-inst-before="cond-branches" -Xptxas --sassi-before-args="cond-branch-info" -g -O3 -dc  -o matrixMul.o matrixMul.cu
>
> ---
>
> *
>   *                       SASSI Instrumentation Details
>   *
>   *  For the settings you passed in, you'll need to make sure that you have
>   *  an instrumentation library with the following properties:
>   *  - It MUST BE compiled using only 16 registers!! To accomplish this
>   *    simply compile your library with the nvcc flag, --maxrregcount=16
>   *  - It must define the following functions:
>   *      **device** void sassi_before_handler(SASSIBeforeParams*,SASSICondBranchParams*)
>   *
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> *
>   *                       SASSI Instrumentation Details
>   *
>   *  For the settings you passed in, you'll need to make sure that you have
>   *  an instrumentation library with the following properties:
>   *  - It MUST BE compiled using only 16 registers!! To accomplish this
>   *    simply compile your library with the nvcc flag, --maxrregcount=16
>   *  - It must define the following functions:
>   *      **device** void sassi_before_handler(SASSIBeforeParams*,SASSICondBranchParams*)
>   *
>   ****************************************************************************** /usr/local/sassi7//bin/nvcc -o matrixMul matrixMul.o -gencode
>   arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50
>   -Xlinker "--wrap=main" -Xlinker "--wrap=exit" -L../instlibs/lib -lbranch -L/usr/local/sassi7//extras/CUPTI/lib64 -lcupti  -lcudadevrt -Xlinker -rpath,/usr/local/sassi7//extras/CUPTI/lib64 -L/lib -lboost_regex -lcrypto -Xlinker -rpath,/lib **nvlink error   : Undefined reference to
>   '_Z20sassi_before_handlerP17SASSIBeforeParamsP21SASSICondBranchParams'
>   in 'matrixMul.o' make: *** [matrixMul] Error 255**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to install Boost, set the appropriate paths in `instlibs/env.mk` and run `make all` from `instlibs/` before trying to build the example code. The paths were set correctly, but not all of the required SASSI libraries had been generated.